# MyApi class raises "TypeError: callBack is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, papaparse

I try to make an API class which holds relevant calls in one place:

```
class Api {

  fetchDataDaily = (callBack) => {
    let FILE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_FILE_DAILY;
    readRemoteFile(FILE_URL, {
      header: true,
      download: true,
      complete: resp => {
        callBack(resp.data);
      },
    });
  };
}
```

From outside I do this:

```
import Api from './Api';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Table extends Component {
  api = new Api();

  logConsole = data => {
    console.log('data: ', data);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.api.fetchDataDaily(this.logConsole);
  }
}
```

What I get is an error:

```
TypeError: callBack is not a function
complete
src/Api.js:33
  30 |     header: true,
  31 |     download: true,
  32 |     complete: resp => {
> 33 |       this.callBack(resp.data);
     | ^  34 |     },
  35 |   });
  36 | };
View compiled
```

- Why?
- And how can I solve that?

Comment: The error message doesn't correspond with the code that you've posted. The error says that `this.callBack` is not a function but in your code, you're calling `callBack` (without the `this.` part).

Comment: oh, yes, that was from a previews attempt. I will delete the 'this'. But in both cases, it raises the error at the same place.

Comment: @Jan Have you tried with `componentDidMount` as an arrow function like: `componentDidMount = () => { ... `?

Comment: the thing is, it logs the data to the console. the error appears after it

Comment: Hah!!!! I found the error. Somewhere in my app, I had another call to the API which doesn't provided a callback. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

The error was, that somewhere in my code, the function was also called, but without a given callback function.

wrong

```
dataApi.fetchDataDaily(date)
```

solved

```
dataApi.fetchDataDaily(date, callback)
```